# Почему не работает SQL запрос в c#?

Tags: c#, sql

При попытке вставить что-то в таблицу и удалить через `SqlCommand` ничего не происходит, код:

```
namespace sql_requests
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string connection_path 
            = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;";

        private static SqlConnection connect;
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            connect = new SqlConnection(connection_path);
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;

            try
            {
                await connect.OpenAsync();
                string[] commands = {"select * from test",
                    "delete from test where name = 'Ivan'",
                    "insert into test (name) values ('Ivan')"};

                cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[2], connect);
                //cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[1], connect);
                cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[0], connect);

                reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                if (reader.HasRows) 
                {
                    string columnName1 = reader.GetName(0);
                    string columnName2 = reader.GetName(1);

                    Console.WriteLine($"{columnName1}\t{columnName2}");

                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        object id = reader.GetValue(0);
                        object name = reader.GetValue(1);

                        Console.WriteLine($"{id} \t{name}");
                    }
                }

                await reader.CloseAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    await connect.CloseAsync();
            }
     
        }
    } 
}
```

На консоль выводится единственная запись сделаная через сам ms sql server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[0], connect); reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(); - Вы одну команду только делаете Select....  Insert - не выполняется :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом фрагменте кода SQL-команда выполняется только один раз.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[2], connect);
//cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[1], connect);
cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[0], connect);
```

Вы присвоили переменной cmd сначала одну строку из массива, а затем сразу же другую. Затем выполнили команду, которая в виде строки хранится в cmd.

```
reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

Так, можно выполнять команды INSERT, UPDATE и DELETE с помощью метода [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netcore-1.1). Например, так:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[2], connect);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[1], connect);
cmd = new SqlCommand(commands[0], connect);
reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```